# How to call swift from .mm?

Tags: swift, opencv, objective-c++

I created a `openCV camera stream` using objc++ and Swift and I ended up with a working project.

**So these are my files:**

*1.openCVWrapper.h*:

```
#import "myProjectDelegate.h"
@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject
    - (void)setCameraDelegate: (id<OpenCVCamDelegate>) delegate;
@end
```

*2.openCVWrapper.mm*:

```
@implementation OpenCVWrapper : NSObject
- (void) setCameraDelegate: (id<OpenCVCamDelegate>) delegate {
    myProject* camera = [myProject myProjectInstance];
    camera.delegate = delegate;
}
@end
```

*3.myProject.h*:

```
@interface myProject : NSObject<CvVideoCameraDelegate> 
@property CvVideoCamera* cam;
@property id<OpenCVCamDelegate> delegate;

+ (id) myProjectInstance;
- (void) initializeCamera;

@end
```

*4.myProject.mm*:

```
static void myStaticFunction() {
   // How to call "CALL_THIS_FUNCTION" from !right! here

}


- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)image {
    if (self.delegate != nil) {
        image = doSomething(image);
        [self.delegate callbackImage: MatToUIImage(image)];
    }
}
```

*5.myProjectDelegate.h*:

```
@protocol OpenCVCamDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) callbackCameraFrame: (UIImage*) image;
@end
```

*6.myProject.swift*:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, OpenCVCamDelegate {
  var OpenCVWrapperInstance: OpenCVWrapper!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     OpenCVWrapperInstance = OpenCVWrapper()
     OpenCVWrapperInstance.setCameraDelegate(self)     
  }

  func CALL_THIS_FUNCTION() {
     print("Yeah, success!");
  }

  func callbackCameraFrame(_ image: UIImage!) {
     // do some stuff with the image
  }
}
```

---

**My question:**

So the camera stream and the delegate to Swift is working quite fine but now I'd like to call the Swift-function `CALL_THIS_FUNCTION` from a static method you can find in `4.myProject.mm:`. Whatever I've already tried doesn't seems to be the right way because till now I could not get it working.

My first idea was to use a delegate in `.myProject.mm` but it whether occurred any error nor it called the swift function. Have a look at my code:

```
id<OpenCVCamDelegate> myDelegate;
static void myStaticFunction() {
    // How to call "CALL_THIS_FUNCTION" from !right! here
    [globalDelegate CALL_THIS_FUNCTION];
}
```

**Note**: Any help how to solve this problem would be really appreciated `:)`

Comment: Would you mind to share some lines because I do not really know how to go on with `give your static function a pointer to your object`? **(Sorry I'm obviously a bloody beginner using Swift&objc++)** - Greetings jonas `:)`

Comment: Who calls/uses myStaticFunction inside your objc code? Who calls "callbackCameraFrame:" method inside your objc code? (you only show code for calling `callbackImage:`, which I assume is `CvVideoCameraDelegate`, not the same as `OpenCVCamDelegate`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I had to do this, but this was the workflow:

1. Mark your Swift class and associated functions you want to expose with `@objc`. (ex: `@objc class ViewController: UIViewController, OpenCVCamDelegate {...}`)
2. In your Obj-C .m file add: `#import <YourProductModuleName>-Swift.h`
3. In the .h add: `@class ViewController` (or other Swift file name)

You can `Command`+`Option` click on the `@class ViewController` to see the -Swift.h header that Xcode generates for you.

You'll want to be sure you're using object types which Obj-C can work with as well.